# Prove that the subdomain $\mathbb{Z}+ 7\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$ of the Euclidean domain $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$ is not Euclidean

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I need help to prove that the subdomain $\mathbb{Z}+ 7\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$ of the Euclidean domain $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$ is not Euclidean.

I have been using the Alaca & Williams book, Introductory Algebraic Number Theory.

Thanks

Comment: No, I don't know, but I tried that way. Also, I tried a proof with universal side divisors, but nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The ring is not integrally closed (contains $2$ but doesn't contain $\sqrt{2}$ which is in its field of fractions), so it can't be a PID, i.e. it is not Euclidean. If you need a reminder, (re)prove that the roots of $x^2-2$ have to be in the ring, provided it is a PID - suppose that $\alpha=\beta/\gamma$ is a root, $\beta,\gamma$ in the ring, no prime dividing both $\beta$ and $\gamma$, implies $\gamma$ is a unit.

Comment: Perhaps one needs also a reminder for the fact that any PID is integrally closed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I changed UFD to PID to make you happier (and the answer clearer)

Comment: Oh, I am happy, don't worry. The answer is fine. It  uses some facts on integral ring extensions (well known for the OP?)

Comment: +1 It also couldn't ever be integrally closed because it's a non-maximal order in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}$.

Comment: Well, I checked my book, and this is in the chapter 4, and my homework is in the chapter 2. But I am tryin to prove that the domain is not a PID with the theory that I have available. Thanks

Comment: I think that 2 is irreducible, but is not prime. With this $\mathbb{Z}+ 7\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$ is not an PID, and then is not an Euclidean domain